# Is series convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Does this series converge?  
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{{(-1)}^{n}(n+2)}{{n}^{2}+4}$$  
How can i step-by-step calculate it?

Comment: sum up two consecutive terms, see what you get

Comment: The ratio or root tests look promising for such a form.

Comment: What convergence tests have you tried?

Comment: The alternating series test since the series has $(-1)^n$ and thus is clearly alternating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that

$$\frac{n+2}{n^2+4}\ge\frac{n+3}{(n+1)^2+4}\iff (n+2)(n^2+2n+5)\ge(n+3)(n^2+4)\iff$$

$$\iff n^3+4n^2+9n+10\ge n^3+3n^2+4n+12\iff$$

$$\iff n^2+5n-2\ge 0$$

and the last inequality is clear since the positive quadratic's root is less than $\;1\;$ .

Thus, your sequence *without the alternating sign* is monotone decreasing and that is thus a Leibniz series so convergent.

Comment: only one root of two will be negative

Comment: You are right @Brown and I shall edit my answer right now, yet the positive root is pretty small (check this:what does it mean?) and that's all we need...:)

Comment: Where i can find info about small root? I can`t find it, maybe i`m looking for something different

Comment: What do you need?? The positive root is $$\frac{-5+\sqrt{33}}2\sim 0.3...$$

Answer (score 2):

We have

$$\frac{{(-1)}^{n}(n+2)}{{n}^{2}+4}=\frac{(-1)^n}{n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$
and the series $\displaystyle\sum \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ is convergent by the Leibniz theorem and the series $\displaystyle\sum O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$ is convergent by comparison with Riemann convergent series hence the given series is convergent.

Answer (score 0):

For the Alternating Series Test, three conditions have to be met in order to show convergence.

1. The limit of $a_n$ must equal $0$
2. $a_n > 0$ $\forall n \in N$
3. $a_n \ge a_{n+1}$

Eliminate the alternating part i.e. $(-1)^n$

Let $$a_n = \frac{(n+2)}{(n^2+4)}$$

Use the $n^{th}$ term test of divergence which states that if 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{(n+2)}{(n^2+4)} \neq 0$$ 
then $\sum a_n$ diverges

So if $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{(n+2)}{(n^2+4)} = 0$$ then continue.

Show that $$\frac{(n+2)}{(n^2+4)} > 0$$ $\forall n \in N$

Show that $$\frac{(n+2)}{(n^2+4)} \ge \frac{(n+3)}{{(n+1)}^2 + 4}$$

If all these three criteria are satisfied then the series converges.

Comment: Some people, instead of giving-requiring a little explanation, prefer to downvote. Disgusting. Anyway @zhoe, you seem to have missed the squared $\;n\;$ in the denominator.

Comment: Your series is not related to the original.

Comment: Oh crap, I didnt see the squared n on the bottom.

Comment: @DonAntonio I was just checking the edit. You should not be so fast about judging.

Comment: I did judge the quick-downvoters, @AlexR...are you one of those? Because if you are then fine, otherwise...?

Comment: Well I changed it now, thanks for the correction.

Comment: I will upvote your post only to cancel the downvote that is there. I really don't think downvoting is the best and nicest thing to do when correcting others.

Answer (score 0):

Going by mm-aops' suggestion, you can look at the sum of two consecutive terms and see what you get. They look like
$$
-\frac{n+2}{n^2+4} + \frac{n+3}{n^2+2n+5} = \frac{(n^2+4)(n+3) - (n^2 + 2n + 5)(n+2)}{(n^2 + 4)(n^2 + 2n + 5)} = \frac{O(n^2)}{O(n^4)}
$$
The precise value of the sum of the two terms isn't really that important, but this shows that the sum of two consecutive terms in the series is $O(1/n^2)$. So, if you just bundle the terms consecutively, you get something that looks like $\sum 1/n^2$, which converges. As for the exact value, that seems quite tricky.

Edit: According to Wolfram Alpha, the sum of this series is [quite bad](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_%7Bn+%3D+1%7D%5Einfinity+%28-1%29%5En%28n%2B2%29%2F%28n%5E2%2B4%29).

Answer (score -2):

$ | \frac{n+2}{n^2+4} |$ = $ \frac{n}{n^2+4} + \frac{2}{n^2+4} \leq \frac{1}{n^2} + \frac{2}{n^2} = \frac{3}{n^2}$ this implies $|a_n|$ is convergent therefore the sequence $a_n$ converges. I guess just go about it carefully

Comment: The series is most definitely not absolutely convergent; it is essentially the (alternating) harmonic series.

Comment: Every absolute convergent sequence is convergent

Comment: Yes, but the series isn't absolutely convergent.

Comment: @user108352, your mistake is in the inequality: it isn't true, of course.

Comment: @DonAntonio Could you please explain where i went wrong ?

Comment: I wrote it, @user108352: if is false that $$\frac{n+2}{n^2+4}\le\frac 3{n^2}$$

Comment: ya i got it now . $\frac{n}{n^2+4} \leq \frac{1}{n^2}$ is not true. Thank you